# maven java project missing artifact

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Hello i'm new to maven project and i've been trying to use the JSON library.
I'm currently using eclipse, coding in java.
The issue was, eclipse wasn't detecting the package org.json

I've added the jar to the buildpath.
I've changed the dependency in the pom.xml
But eclipse keeps telling me i have an error in the pom.xml :
`missing artifact org.json:json-java:jar:20230618`

i've also tryed to change the version number ; 1.0 or 20230618

I'm not sure how to proceed, am i supposed to write in the pom.xml where to find the jar ?
Here is the dependency i wrote in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-java</artifactId>
        <version>20230618</version>
        <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

the jar is named json-java.jar

Thanks for your time

Comment: "jar" is not usually part of the artifact coordinates. The repository you're using will often generate the correct dependency stanza for you.

Comment: It's without `<type>jar</type>` (as nitind already said) and `<artifactId>json</artifactId>` instead of `<artifactId>json-java</artifactId>`. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20230618

Comment: ...and change the POM only (not the build path of Eclipse), then right-click on the POM and select "Maven/Update project" to be sure that the build path gets updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed howlger recommandation ;
remove the type line, change json-java by json
and it was good.